# Can't read .docx file which i got after converting pdf using soffice command

Tags: python, pdf, docx, python-docx, soffice

I am trying to convert pdf to docx using soffice. It converts it into .docx but it gives textboxes which I am unable to read using the [docx api](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provided by python. Is there any better way to read the file or any better way to convert pdf to docx so that I do not get textboxes?

```
soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx "convert_this.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Aspose.Words for Cloud to convert PDF to Word documents.
https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/wordscloud/Convert+PDF+Document+to+Word
It converts PDF from fixed form to flow form so it is editable in MS Word.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.